# How to keep session unchanged in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, shopping-cart, sessionid

I'm trying to create a shopping cart by storing the cart in a table in a database, instead of using the built-in CI cart class. I use sessionID to identify one visitor from another. But I found that the sessionID is changing for a period of time, even the visitor doesn't close the browser.

Is this a normal behavior of CI to renew the sessionID for a short period of time? Is there a way to make it unchanged until the visitor close the browser?

Thank you at advance.

Comment: You can also store the (reference to a) cart in a CI-session. The other way around. Makes more sense. I never noticed the session ID change during a session, should not happen.

Comment: @PatrickSavalle, but it's true in CI, the session id is changing like every 5 minutes. But then I can use the generic session generated by the browser itself, not by CI session by starting up the `session_start()` and get the `session_id()`. Now the session id remains the same during the session.

Answer (score 3):

Also, make sure in your config file you have cookie_prefix set.. see bottom of: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

If your session is contstantly being reset using the CI Session library, make sure the cookie domain is set to something like:

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.mysite.com'; // the . is for a wildcard subdomain
```